# trying: "venv\scripts\activate" error:"venv\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to activate a virtual environment using `venv\scripts\activate` on Windows 10 but I keep on getting an error `The system cannot find the path specified.` What am I doing wrong? The error comes when I try to activate the venv after navigating to its directory using `cd venv`.

I tried navigating to the `venv` directory and ran `scripts\activate` but I get an error `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: Have you tried `./venv/scripts/activate`?

Comment: The command `venv\scripts\activate` assumes that you have _not_ already navigated to the `venv` directory.

Answer (score 0):

First create a virtual environment:

```
py -m venv env
```

then activate the VM:

```
env\scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

In vscode, you can use interface-based operations to create and activate a virtual environment. `Ctrl+Shift+P`-->**Python: Create Environment**, read [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_using-the-create-environment-command) for details.

[image]

You can also create and activate a virtual environment [using the command line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment-in-the-terminal).

[image]

In addition, select the virtual environment in the **Select Interpreter** panel, and then create a new terminal to automatically activate the virtual environment.

[image]